# Trouble opening Ubuntu 14.04 after update on chromebook C720

Tags: 14.04, chromebook

After I updated ubuntu on my chromebook (Acer C720) I'm unable to get to ubuntu from the chromebook's terminal. After I login, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

Would anyone know the best course of action in order to remediate this? In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was just in the same predicament that you're in and I promised myself (sort of) that if I were to figure this out myself i'll help the rest with this issue, and I FIGURED IT OUT!

All you have to do is update your chroot or crouton with the following command line within the ChromeOS terminal:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n -u <chrootname>
```

With chrootname being the name of your chroot (precise, trusty, etc.).
Based on your error, your chroot name is "precise", so you'll input this as the following command line:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u
```

If you get some kind of error then it's more than likely that you've deleted your crouton file. Redownload that file here http://goo.gl/fd3zc if you did. 
Then go back to the whole update crouton deal I just told you about. I hope this helps you dude!